# Can I freeze (unbaked) pate a choux?

Tags: freezing, pastry

Can I keep it in the freezer without issue for days? Weeks? Months?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't– in my experience, the paste won't puff well if it's been sitting around even for a couple of hours. Baked choux paste freezes very well though– your best bet is to make it into profiteroles or eclairs or gougères or whatever and freeze those if you've got the space.